# Figurative language of walkabout by James Marshall

Tags: figurative

Can anyone point out the figurative languages used in walkabout? Or is there any guide book for walkabout?

Comment: You mean the book, *Walkabout*, by James Marshall, as mentioned at ["Walkabout: a retelling"](http://walkaboutthebook.blogspot.com/2007/02/walk-about-by-james-vance-marshall.html), correct?

Comment: If you are asking for comments on the symbolic language used in the book, your question is off-topic here. See: For a book that’s only 120 pages, small pages at that, it’s so densely layered with symbolism as if to verge on being overwrought. Yet the book is saved by its focused narrative path, interior character portraits, and lush descriptions of the outback. http://therumpus.net/2012/05/walkabout/

Comment: I have been given to understand that there is an Australian expression -- "gone walkabout" -- which literally means a trip that an Aboriginal periodically takes as a sort of a pilgrimage, but which is used metaphorically to mean that someone has gone a bit bonkers and is, at least figuratively, wandering around aimlessly.

Answer (score 1):

It comes from Australian English and refers to local migrations:  [walkabout](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=walkabout%20&searchmode=none):

> - "periodic migration by a westernized Aboriginal into the bush," 1828, Australian English, from walk (v.) + about.

(Etymonline)

[Walkabout](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walkabout):

> - refers to a rite of passage during which male Australian Aborigines would undergo a journey during adolescence and live in the wilderness for a period as long as six months.
> - In this practice they would trace the paths, or "songlines", that their ancestors took, and imitate, in a fashion, their heroic deeds. Merriam-Webster, however, identifies the noun as a 1908 coinage referring to "a short period of wandering bush life engaged in by an Australian Aborigine as an occasional interruption of regular work", with the only mention of "spiritual journey" coming in a usage example from a latter-day travel writer.

Wikipedia